# How to prevent that the same .travis.yml needs to be copied to every repo over and over again?

Tags: travis-ci

**Background:** At the moment there are multiple modules: [puppet-sftp](https://github.com/030/puppet-sftp), [puppet-git](https://github.com/030/puppet-git), [puppet-packer](https://github.com/030/puppet-packer) and [puppet-otto](https://github.com/030/puppet-otto) that use the same .travis.yml.

**Aim:** to create a [common .travis.yml](https://github.com/030/puppet-otto/issues/7) instead of copying it over and over again

**Methods:**

1. A [common git repo](https://github.com/030/puppet-common-test) has been created
2. [This repo](https://github.com/030/puppet-otto/compare/gh7_avoid_code_duplication_travis?expand=1) is cloned in every project using travis

**Results:**

```
The command "ls" exited with 0.

$ npm ansible-common-test/test

Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:

    add-user, adduser, apihelp, author, bin, bugs, c, cache,

    completion, config, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, docs, edit,

    explore, faq, find, find-dupes, get, help, help-search,

    home, i, info, init, install, isntall, issues, la, link,

    list, ll, ln, login, ls, outdated, owner, pack, prefix,

    prune, publish, r, rb, rebuild, remove, repo, restart, rm,

    root, run-script, s, se, search, set, show, shrinkwrap,

    star, stars, start, stop, submodule, t, tag, test, tst, un,

    uninstall, unlink, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v,

    version, view, whoami
```

attempt2

```
$ sh ansible-common-test/test.sh

ansible-common-test/test.sh: 4: ansible-common-test/test.sh: ---: not found

ansible-common-test/test.sh: 5: ansible-common-test/test.sh: sudo:: not found

ansible-common-test/test.sh: 7: ansible-common-test/test.sh: env:: not found

ansible-common-test/test.sh: 8: ansible-common-test/test.sh: -: not found

ansible-common-test/test.sh: 9: ansible-common-test/test.sh: version:: not found

ansible-common-test/test.sh: 10: ansible-common-test/test.sh: init:: not found

ansible-common-test/test.sh: 11: ansible-common-test/test.sh: run_opts:: not found

ansible-common-test/test.sh: 13: ansible-common-test/test.sh: services:: not found

ansible-common-test/test.sh: 14: ansible-common-test/test.sh: -: not found

ansible-common-test/test.sh: 16: ansible-common-test/test.sh: before_install:: not found

ansible-common-test/test.sh: 18: ansible-common-test/test.sh: -: not found

ansible-common-test/test.sh: 20: ansible-common-test/test.sh: -: not found

ansible-common-test/test.sh: 22: ansible-common-test/test.sh: script:: not found

ansible-common-test/test.sh: 23: ansible-common-test/test.sh: -: not found

ansible-common-test/test.sh: 25: ansible-common-test/test.sh: -: not found

ansible-common-test/test.sh: 31: ansible-common-test/test.sh: -: not found

ansible-common-test/test.sh: 34: ansible-common-test/test.sh: -: not found

ansible-common-test/test.sh: 38: ansible-common-test/test.sh: Syntax error: newline unexpected
```

**Discussion:**

The duplicate code from the .travis.yml was moved to a common repo and neither a .sh nor the yml could be run. No matter what is tried it does not seem to possible to run the travis code from a common repo in order to avoid code duplication.

The expectation is the following:

1. Common repo that contains the [.travis.yml](https://github.com/030/puppet-otto/blob/master/.travis.yml) that is used by every repo is cloned by travis
2. The common code is run

Comment: Sorry, I do not really understand what problem you are trying to solve, and how they relate to the errors that you display. How much cognitive overload are you prepared to take to avoid to type `cp /path/to/travis.yml.skel .travis.yml`?

Comment: The problem is that a lot of time is lot as if I make a change to one travis file then I have to implement the same change in the travis files of all repos. I have now 4 repos and all of them have the same travis.yml. I just want to use 1 travis.yml. Copying is sufficient? So git clone the common repo and then changing the name to .travis.yml will work?

Comment: Well, it sounds like you want to have two git repositories in one project folder. If that would be possible at all, that would be needlessly complicated. Just write a script to update `.travis.yml` whenever you update the original one.